# Oracle ORDER BY throwing ORA-01785

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I'm building an Oracle query to count some scores of a patient in a hospital stay. In the last row, I want to print out the total of all the score columns and this works. My problem is: I want to order by the date column, which I had to cast to char for the right format for my country.

This is the query:

```
SELECT "Fallnummer", 
       TO_CHAR("Datum", 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS "Datum", 
       TO_CHAR("Summe (subtotal)") AS "Summe (subtotal)",
       "SAPS Alter",
       "SAPS Herzfrequenz"
FROM (
    SELECT
        f.FALLNR AS "Fallnummer", e.VON AS "Datum", scp.BEZEICHNUNG, s.PUNKTE, SUM (s.PUNKTE) OVER (ORDER BY e.VON) AS "Summe (subtotal)"
    FROM
        FALL f
    INNER JOIN OS_MUP.EINSTUFUNG e ON
        e.FALLID = f.FALLID
    INNER JOIN OS_MUP.EINSTUFUNGSRANG einr ON
        einr.EINSTUFUNGID = e.EINSTUFUNGID
    INNER JOIN OS_MUP.SCORERANG s ON
        s.SCORERANGID = einr.SCORERANGID
    INNER JOIN OS_MUP.SCOREPOSITION scp ON
        scp.SCOREPOSITIONID = s.SCOREPOSITIONID
    WHERE
        f.FALLNR = 12345678
    )
    
    PIVOT (SUM(PUNKTE) FOR BEZEICHNUNG IN (
        'Alter' AS "SAPS Alter", 
        'Herzfrequenz' AS "SAPS Herzfrequenz", 
        'Systolischer Blutdruck' AS "SAPS RR Syst.", 
        'Körpertemperatur' AS "SAPS Temperatur", 
        'PaO2/FiO2' AS "SAPS Pa/Fi", 
        'Ausfuhr Urin' AS "SAPS Urin", 
        'Harnstoff im Serum' AS "SAPS Harnstoff", 
        'Leukozyten' AS "SAPS Leukozyten", 
        'Kalium im Serum' AS "SAPS Kalium", 
        'Natrium im Serum' AS "SAPS Natrium", 
        'Bicarbonat im Serum' AS "SAPS Bicarbonat",
        'Bilirubin im Serum' AS "SAPS Bilirubin",
        'Chronische Leiden' AS "SAPS Chron. Leiden",
        'Aufnahmestatus' AS "SAPS Status",
        'Apparative Beatmung' AS "TISS Beatmung",
        'Infusion multipler Katecholamine (>1)' AS "TISS Katech.",
        'Flüssigkeitersatz in hohen Mengen (>5l/24Std.)' AS "TISS Fl. Ersatz",
        'Peripherer arterieller Katheter' AS "TISS Per. Art. Kath.",
        'Linksvorhof-Katheter / Pulmonalis-Katheter' AS "TISS LK/PK",
        'Hämofiltration / Dialyse' AS "TISS Dialyse",
        'Intrakranielle Druckmessung' AS "TISS Intr. Druckmessung",
        'Behandlung einer metabolischen Azidose/Alkalose' AS "TISS Azidose",
        'Spezielle Intervention auf der ITS' AS "TISS Interv.",
        'Aktionen außerhalb der Station (Diagnostik/Operation)' AS "TISS Akt. auss."
        )
    )
    
    UNION

    SELECT '12345678' "Fallnummer", 
           MAX(TO_CHAR("Datum", 'DD.MM.YYYY')) AS "Datum", 
           '-' "Summe (subtotal)",
           SUM("SAPS Alter"),
           SUM("SAPS Herzfrequenz")
    FROM (
        SELECT
            f.FALLNR AS "Fallnummer", e.VON AS "Datum", scp.BEZEICHNUNG, s.PUNKTE, SUM (s.PUNKTE) OVER (ORDER BY e.VON) AS "Summe (subtotal)"
        FROM
            FALL f
        INNER JOIN OS_MUP.EINSTUFUNG e ON
            e.FALLID = f.FALLID
        INNER JOIN OS_MUP.EINSTUFUNGSRANG einr ON
            einr.EINSTUFUNGID = e.EINSTUFUNGID
        INNER JOIN OS_MUP.SCORERANG s ON
            s.SCORERANGID = einr.SCORERANGID
        INNER JOIN OS_MUP.SCOREPOSITION scp ON
            scp.SCOREPOSITIONID = s.SCOREPOSITIONID
        WHERE
            f.FALLNR = 12345678
        ) 
        PIVOT (SUM(PUNKTE) FOR BEZEICHNUNG IN (
            'Alter' AS "SAPS Alter", 
            'Herzfrequenz' AS "SAPS Herzfrequenz", 
            'Systolischer Blutdruck' AS "SAPS RR Syst.", 
            'Körpertemperatur' AS "SAPS Temperatur", 
            'PaO2/FiO2' AS "SAPS Pa/Fi", 
            'Ausfuhr Urin' AS "SAPS Urin", 
            'Harnstoff im Serum' AS "SAPS Harnstoff", 
            'Leukozyten' AS "SAPS Leukozyten", 
            'Kalium im Serum' AS "SAPS Kalium", 
            'Natrium im Serum' AS "SAPS Natrium", 
            'Bicarbonat im Serum' AS "SAPS Bicarbonat",
            'Bilirubin im Serum' AS "SAPS Bilirubin",
            'Chronische Leiden' AS "SAPS Chron. Leiden",
            'Aufnahmestatus' AS "SAPS Status",
            'Apparative Beatmung' AS "TISS Beatmung",
            'Infusion multipler Katecholamine (>1)' AS "TISS Katech.",
            'Flüssigkeitersatz in hohen Mengen (>5l/24Std.)' AS "TISS Fl. Ersatz",
            'Peripherer arterieller Katheter' AS "TISS Per. Art. Kath.",
            'Linksvorhof-Katheter / Pulmonalis-Katheter' AS "TISS LK/PK",
            'Hämofiltration / Dialyse' AS "TISS Dialyse",
            'Intrakranielle Druckmessung' AS "TISS Intr. Druckmessung",
            'Behandlung einer metabolischen Azidose/Alkalose' AS "TISS Azidose",
            'Spezielle Intervention auf der ITS' AS "TISS Interv.",
            'Aktionen außerhalb der Station (Diagnostik/Operation)' AS "TISS Akt. auss."
            )
        )
ORDER BY
    TO_DATE("Datum")
```

Normally I could just do `ORDER BY TO_DATE("Datum")`, which was working in my old query as well, but now it's throwing me this error:

```
ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression
```

Why can't I do the cast anymore to order the records?

Comment: Did you try `ORDER BY 2`?

Comment: Yeah I did try, but doesn't change anything. And that doesn't solve the problem with the cast.

Comment: ORDER BY 2 won't work; it is a *string* (not number 2 itself, but what it represents - a TO_CHAR() result) so all "first-in-the-month" will be sorted first, regardless month and/or year they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

try to do 'order by TO_Date (datum)' up like you have done in the second piece of the union.

Comment: That's not for the second piece of the union, it's for the SELECT which is combining both SELECTS from the UNION.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because of `UNION`. One option is to select actual `DATE` datatype value (in both `SELECT`s), i.e.

```
select "Datum", ...
```

and then sort by it.

Or, you could apply different format mask to it, e.g.

```
select to_char("Datum", 'yyyymmdd') as "Datum"
```

which will let you sort values correctly.

---

Also, whenever using `TO_DATE`, provide appropriate format mask. Don't just `to_char("Datum")`, make it e.g. `to_char("Datum", 'dd.mm.yyyy')`.

Finally, if you can, **never** use double quotes with any object names in Oracle. That makes your life miserable as you always have to use double quotes, and never miss a letter case.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. The original format of the Date is like this: 2019-01-25 00:00:00, so it's rather a timestamp. Now when I use TO_DATE("Datum", 'dd.mm.yyyy') it's giving me this weird result: 0019-01-25 00:00:00 - any idea? Do I have to extract the date first?

Comment: Ah, sorry; I was thinking on DATE and wrote an answer as if it was a VARCHAR2. It depends on what datatype the "Datum" column is. I thought it was a DATE; if so, you'd apply TO_CHAR to it (not TO_DATE as I initially wrote) and use appropriate format mask. Using TO_DATE on a DATE datatype is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

one way you can try is to keep the timestamp column as it is in your query, create a different column which will be converted to TO_CHAR, and from the time stamp column select only the MM/DD/YYYY part which you need (and may be  HH:MI:SS if you need hr, min and sec)

thanks